Lambda Service Quota increase cannot be increased above 10, how do I increase the lambda concurrency quota?
AWS Lambda quota value is listed as 10, and through the Request Quota Increase form via Service Quotas page in AWS Console I am given an error response claiming I must choose a value larger than 1000.  My account is not new, it was created about a year prior and I've been using lambda functions daily for about 2 months.
I've gone to the service quotas page and requested an increase to 30.
The error I see says "You must provide a quota value greater than the default quota value of 1000.00" -- I want a value closer to 30 is this possible?
From the service quota documentation I've read, I shouldn't be facing this issue.
How can I increase my quota for concurrent lambda functions?
Image of the error in my service quotas page,  I can't embed because SO account is too new

Can you simply increase it to 1000? If you want to limit concurrent executions of a specific Lambda function, you can assign Reserved Concurrency to that function.

Please go through this documentation, it should give you a fair idea about the topic. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase

By default AWS gives you a quote of 1000 concurrent executions across all lambda functions for all regions in your account and you can request a quota increase. The error you are getting is maybe because the minimum is 1000.
For each lambda you can reserve concurrency up to account limits and that concurrency will only be used on that lambda. Also you can provision a lambda with concurrency to avoid cold starts and have your lambdas always warn.
You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html
Edit:
Seems like AWS place specifics limits on new AWS Accounts, these quotas are increased automatically based on your usage. You can request a quota increase from the Service Quota's console. That's why you have 10 concurrent executions applied in your account and the default quota value is 1000.
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

Thank you, but this answer as well as the others ignore the issue that I'm experiencing.  I'm stuck with an "Applied account-level quota value" of 10 and there appears to be no way to increase beyond 10.  Regardless of reserved concurrency settings, I cannot run more than 10 lambda functions at once.  Increasing the service quota is not helpful because the account-level quota is still well above 10 at 1000.  How can the "Applied" account level quota be increased? This is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation linked.

Seems like AWS placed specifics limits on new AWS Accounts, these quotas are increased automatically based on your usage. Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

PD: I edited my answer
